# Advice on list/look up table/hash table?

Tags: php

I have a fairly simple (at least I thought simple) task I'm trying to achieve but for the life of me I can't think of the best way of doing it in php.

Note I'm trying to avoid using nested multi-dimensional arrays.

What I want to do is a simple 2 axis reference table which I can query/look up against.

```
    0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
0   5   0   0   0   0   0
-
1   0   2   0   1   0   0
-
2   0   0   0   7   0   1
-
3   1   2   4   10  1   0
-
4   0   0   0   0   0   0
-
5   0   3   4   0   1   0
```

Then I want to query it so lookup_table(3,3) would return 10.  I also need to update the values in the table so like add_lookup_table(3,3,1) would change location 3,3 to 11 or some variation of.

So far I know I can achieve it with multidim arrays however want to avoid this because its just going to be a pain in the ass getting and setting each time.
I thought about a list() but php's lists aren't really lists so that goes out the window.

What I'm after is suggestions/recommendations for a better way of doing this.

Comment: You know you don't have to initialize full 2D array with `0`, just `$hashTable = array(); $hashTable[3][3] = 10; ...`?

Comment: You can use an array of objects. Each object has 3 properties `x`, `y`,`value`. Your `toString` function might need some thinking but the logic and implementation should be easy.

Comment: @justinas i am aware of that but it's going to get far too complex dealing with arrays of arrays what I need is basically a double keyed array tbh.

Comment: So an array of objects isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: @Dave I don't think there is simpler way than 2D array. And have no idea what's so complicated can be...

Comment: try it, load up a 2d array with 1 mill x 1 mill x y's random generated then try working out which to reference and which not to.  Lets for the sake of simplicity assume that what I'm trying to achieve is far far far more complex than above i just wanted some suggestions as I was having a spazzy moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use a single array like so

```
$array = array(
   5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 2, 0, 1, 0 , 0 
   ..etc...
);
```

then each key is just `$array[$row * 6 + $column]`

so `$array[3*6 + 3]`

or define your array as something like

```
$array["3.3"] = 10;
```

both of the above are BAD ways to do it when a multidimensional array exists and is well suited for the task.

you list the reason you dont want to use it as "getting and setting each time" - what ever the solution, you will have to get and set to populate it.

The real solution here seems to be the one you wish to avoid

you MAY want to check

http://php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php

That has extra structures

Comment: I wish to avoid them as the whole task is alot more complex than posted I've tried to simplify it down otherwise it'll start getting obscene for a post.  We're talking a 1 mill x 1 mill element grid with reference point containing a further object of elements (which may well end up being an array) I'm trying to avoid arrays for the primary grid due to excessive memory usage/lack of speed/general complexity.  I'm also considering moving the store into something such as memcache or perhaps hadoop or mapreduce but I wanted to get the proof of concept and the data in a useable format first

Comment: Having said that http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php looks like it will work as a map should give me what I need.I think